# Find and Extract value from word (different formats) and paste it

Tags: excel, vba

Fetch invoice number from different word files

[image]

I am trying to copy Invioce number from different word files but it only works for one case.
The code I am using is:

```
Found = InStr(1, wdRng, "Invoice Number", vbTextCompare)

                    'If  ID is found, get ID only
                    If Found > 0 Then                            

                        'Get ID by replacing the prefix with space.
                        ResultId = Trim(Replace(wdRng, "Invoice Number", ""))

                        xlsh.Cells(2, 8).Value = ResultId

                        Exit For

                    End If
```

Comment: what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: @vmrvictor Most of them are returning just the text (without value) and some are returning complete blank